# jmeter - Is it possible to duplicate value of a form input

Tags: jmeter

I'm using jmeter to make a POST request (submit a form). I have email and confirm email fields which must be identical. If I generate a random email address for the "Email" field, how can I use it for the "Confirm Email" field? This is the function for the random email address:

`${__RandomString(${__Random(3,9,)},abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz,)}@${__RandomString(${__Random(2,3,)},abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz,)}.${__RandomString(${__Random(2,3,)},abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz,)}`

Answer (score 1):

You can use i.e. [Set Variables Action](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/SetVariablesAction/) to create a variable, i.e. `email` before you will use it the first time:

[image]

Once done you will be able to refer the generated value as `${email}` where required:

[image]

**Set Variables Action** plugin can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-plugins-manager)